# obtain shell prompt in python

Tags: shell, zsh, python

I want to obtain the (zsh) shell prompt in a python script. Simply using

```
import os
prompt = os.environ['PS1']
```

seems not to be the right way, because `PS1` is usually not forwarded to subprocesses. In the same manner `env | grep PS` in a shell fails.

So I concluded that I should probably start an interactive shell as subprocess and querry its prompt. From a shell I can just do

```
zsh -c -i 'echo $PS1'
```

(must be single quotes, double quotes fail)

I tried to do the same from python(2.7) with `subprocess` like this:

```
print subprocess.check_output(['-i','-c',r"'echo $PS1'"],executable="/bin/zsh")
```

This fails with

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['-i', '-c', "'echo $PS1'"]' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

I think this is not because of the `$PS1` but due to the way how i provide the echo-part as argument, because also echoing bare strings in this way fails.

Trying back and forth various combinations I ended up with

```
prompt =  subprocess.check_output("""zsh -c -i 'echo $PS1'""",shell=True,executable="/bin/zsh")
```

which seems to do the job but seems wrong to me as this is starting a shell and in that shell calling yet another shell with `-c -i 'echo $PS1'`.

What's the correct way of obtaining the shell prompt.

Comment: It seems to me, that the kwarg `executable` does not, what you think it does. It is used to replace the executable from the given command line. With `shell=False` it will replace the first element of the argument list, with `shell=True` it will be used as the shell instead of `sh`. It is not usually needed. [See here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print subprocess.check_output(['zsh','-i','-c','echo $PS1'])
```

When running `zsh` from another shell, the quotes around `echo $PS1` are necessary so that the whole string is passed as the single argument after `-c`.  They had to be *single* quotes because in double-quotes, the first shell would have expanded `$PS1`.

In Python, the whole command is a single string, so it is quoted like any other string.  Adding a second set is like typing `'echo $PS1'` (with the quotes) into `zsh` - the shell looks for, and fails to find, an executable named `'echo $PS1'`.

Comment: There is an issue with this approach! Try this for example: `print subprocess.check_output(['zsh','-i','-c','date'])`. It causes Python shell to stop.

Comment: @coffeMug Fascinating.  It seems to be OK for shell built-ins, but if the shell needs to start another process, a stop signal gets sent back up to the Python shell.  I'll investigate further.

Comment: The unexpected stop is down to two interactive shells handling job-control.  It only occurs when using a Python shell (rather than a script) **and** using `-i` with `-c` (unusual but necessary for this problem) **and** using external executables in the command (not required for this problem).

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way is to call subprocess as follows:

```
>>> prompt = subprocess.check_output("""echo $PS1""",shell=True,executable="/bin/zsh")
```

Then you can check the result by `>>> prompt` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
or you can use call to see the results directly:

```
>>> subprocess.call("""echo $PS1""",shell=True,executable="/bin/zsh")
```

So you don't need call `zsh` in the command itself.

To communicate interactively `Popen` can be used:

```
>>> Popen(["/bin/zsh"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
SHELL_PROMPT% echo $PS1    
SHELL_PROMPT% exit  # exit to see the result of command
```

For more about this see [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html)

Also notice the warning about using `shell=True` from above link:

> Warning: Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of shell=True is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input:
>
> ```
> >>> from subprocess import call
> >>> filename = input("What file would you like to display?\n")
> What file would you like to display?
> non_existent; rm -rf / #
> >>> call("cat " + filename, shell=True) # Uh-oh. This will end badly...
> shell=False does not suffer from this vulnerability; the above Note may be helpful in getting code using shell=False to work.
> ```

Comment: This doesn't start `zsh` interactively, so the prompt isn't initialized as required.  On the machine where I could test `zsh`, the result was what was set in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Interesting, but the second and third are not what I'm looking for, it should really run in a python script used like `python somestuff.py` i.e. run noninteractively. The first also doesn't do the job as the `-i` is essential to set the prompt (at least for most default prompts and the user defined prompts i've seen so far).

Comment: @pseyfert there is a way to call `zsh` interactively but I think for your needs the answer by JigglyNaga fits better.